# spring cloud stream RabbitMQ: messages published with delivery_mode=1 when republishToDlq=true

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-cloud-stream

I have a simple application with a producer and a consumer, with the following configuration:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          binder: rabbit
          destination: dest
          group: gname
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          dest:
            consumer:
              autoBindDlq: true
              durableSubscription: true
              requeueRejected: false
              republishToDlq: true
            producer:
              deliveryMode: persistent
```

Messages published to the normal queue are delivered with "delivery_mode: 2", so persistent. Messages republished to the DLQ are delivered with "delivery_mode: 1", so not persistent.

How can I set the delivery_mode=2 for the DLQ republishing?

btw, setting "republishToDlq: false" messages are delivered with "delivery_mode: 2", but I would like using republishToDlq and the features implemented in RepublishMessageRecoverer.

Answer (score 0):

The binder doesn't currently support changing the delivery mode when republishing to the DLQ.

Feel free to open a new feature request on [github issues](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/issues).

Comment: thanks, I created https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/issues/53